# Do routers and networks have have a “max threads” configuration?

Tags: networking, load-testing, bottleneck

I've been stress testing my application now and I've identified a high average network connection time. This is odd because I haven't gone over the max bandwith at all.

What can this be caused by? Have I gone over the "max thread limit" on the router/network if there is such a thing?

I am not good at networking at all so all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Networks and routers don't have "max thread limit", but they are limited by number of packets per seconds, what can manage. Ie. when you're using ping with small packets, you can saturate router with too many requests without saturating bandwidth. This is often uses in DDoS attacks.